Validating API input from input parameter
In my controller I have something like this:
public async Task<Teacher?> GetTeacher(string id){}

All I want to do is throw some sort of BadRequest() or any other appropriate thing for an id validation of the input param.
and logic being something like this:
    if (id == "nah")
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

Well, the problem I am having is my controller is strongly typed to Task<Teacher?> which is fine when I do find a result and I am returning it of that type but it won't compile/cannot cast now if I have a return BadRequest();
So what's a simple way to do a super simple parameter validation like that?

Is it possible to make BadRequest() a property or collection of Teacher?  Or use inheritance so that Teacher inherits the BadRequest class?

Just make it return an ActionResult, eg (in your asynchronous case a Task<ActionResult<Teacher?>>

@devlincarnate "Or use inheritance".. Nooo

@flackoverstow - why noooooo?

With WebAPI2, when annotating your method with [HttpGet("/GetTeacher/{id:string})"] you can directly add some validation - also see the regex possibility in the first link below, which might help you with a more complex validation. You could try to change the return type to IActionResult and return something like Ok(FoundTeacher) in case of success while returning a BadRequest on validation error.
Route constraints in WebAPI2 - MSDC
Return types in WebAPI - MSDC

Good options . I’ll study the links

Note that route constraints will result in 404 for requests that don't match. In other words you can have two routes "/{id:int}" and "/{name}". The 2nd route would only be used for non-numeric requests.

I handle this situation in the following way:
Create an error class:
public class PersistantEntity
{
    public ModelStateDictionary Errors { get; set; }
}

It doesn't have to be type ModelStateDictionary.  Use whatever is the best type for your errors.
And then your Teacher class can inherit the PersistentEntity class:
public class Teacher : PersistantEntity
{
}

And then you can reference that in the Controller with:
 model.Errors = new ModelStateDictionary();
 //do something with model.Errors

And you would just return model (which is of type Teacher) from your Controller, and then do whatever with model.Errors in whatever is handling the return.
Personally, I do my validation in a method contained within the model, not in the Controller.  But then I call it from the Controller with:
 model.Validate();
 //then do something with model.Errors


Good idea . I just don’t really have a model class . It’s just the POCO DTO class and an input parameter
